# XML child nodes showing up under parent nodes where they don't belong

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm getting some weird results in VB trying to parse an XML file.  I'm trying to parse a list of tags (preceded by the "--") for each display.  Instead, each display section is listing the entire list of tags in the XML file instead of just the tags that are assigned to the display.

This is what I want to get:

```
C1_L2_4FRAC
--04PC6016
--04PC6016TQ
C1_L2_4TOPPER
--04PC6400
--04PC6400TQ
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
C1_L2_4FRAC
--04PC6016
--04PC6016TQ
--04PC6400
--04PC6400TQ
C1_L2_4TOPPER
--04PC6016
--04PC6016TQ
--04PC6400
--04PC6400TQ
```

Here is the XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16le"?>
<DisplaysCfg>
<DISPLAY NAME="C1_L2_4FRAC">
  <SYMBOL NAME="PG_ALARMSYMBOL_X2">
    <POSITION X="180" Y="173"/>
    <ACTION NAME="Load Page" PARAM="PG_ALARMLIST_x2,T=04PC6016,T=04PC6016TQ"/>
    <TAG NAME="04PC6016" INDEX="566" DATA_PROC="Infinet.DCS"/>
    <TAG NAME="04PC6016TQ" INDEX="567" DATA_PROC="Infinet.DOL"/>
    <PARAMS DTLS=" GHOSTCLICKPT = FALSE"/>
  </SYMBOL>
</DISPLAY>
<DISPLAY NAME="C1_L2_4TOPPER">
  <SYMBOL NAME="PG_ALARMSYMBOL_X2">
    <POSITION X="1410" Y="154"/>
    <ACTION NAME="Load Page" PARAM="PG_ALARMLIST_x2,T=04PC6400,T=04PC6400TQ"/>
    <TAG NAME="04PC6400" INDEX="583" DATA_PROC="Infinet.DCS"/>
    <TAG NAME="04PC6400TQ" INDEX="584" DATA_PROC="Infinet.DOL"/>
    <PARAMS DTLS=" GHOSTCLICKPT = FALSE"/>
  </SYMBOL>
</DISPLAY>
</DisplaysCfg>
```

And here is the code in question:

```
For Each displaynode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("/DisplaysCfg")
            Dim screenname As String = ""
            For Each attrib As XmlElement In displaynode
                screenname = attrib.GetAttribute("NAME")
                Debug.Print(screenname)
                For Each symbolnode In displaynode.SelectNodes("./DISPLAY/SYMBOL")
                    For Each tagattrib As XmlElement In symbolnode
                        If tagattrib.Name = "TAG" Then
                            Debug.Print("--" & tagattrib.GetAttribute("NAME"))
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're looping through both symbol nodes a second time when using
 For Each symbolnode In displaynode.SelectNodes("./DISPLAY/SYMBOL")

Comment: FYI, why not use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument? It's a lot easier to use, especially from VB.NET.

Comment: That's the part that is confusing me.  Shouldn't the displaynode.SelectNodes("./DISPLAY/SYMBOL") only show the child nodes of the current displaynode?  Instead, it lists every tag in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Never done this before, but after a little reading maybe this is what your looking for:

```
For Each displaynode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("/DisplaysCfg")
            Dim screenname As String = ""
            For Each Attrib As XmlElement In displaynode
                Debug.print(Attrib.GetAttribute("NAME"))
            Next
            For Each symbolnode In displaynode.ChildNodes
                For Each tagattrib As XmlElement In symbolnode
                    If tagattrib.Name = "TAG" Then
                        Debug.Print("--" & tagattrib.GetAttribute("NAME"))
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/XML/GetElementsByTagNameandLoopthroughNodes.htm

Looks like you were just selecting the nodes back from the root and not from inside of displaynode causing it to ignore it and get ran twice.

Answer (score 0):

That's because for each `<DISPLAY>` element, you're iterating through *all* `<SYMBOL>` elements :

```
For Each symbolnode In displaynode.SelectNodes("./DISPLAY/SYMBOL")
```

Notice that above XPath is relative to `displaynode` which refer to `<DisplaysCfg>` element. So the XPath is evaluated against entire XML document.

Change the XPath to be selecting child nodes from current `attrib` and you are good to go :

```
For Each displaynode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("/DisplaysCfg")
    Dim screenname As String = ""
    For Each attrib As XmlElement In displaynode
        screenname = attrib.GetAttribute("NAME")
        Debug.Print(screenname)
        'Notes changes at the following line: '
        For Each symbolnode In attrib.SelectNodes("./*")
            For Each tagattrib As XmlElement In symbolnode
                If tagattrib.Name = "TAG" Then
                    Debug.Print("--" & tagattrib.GetAttribute("NAME"))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```